# making Date Mon in one column equal to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql

In my table i'm having two fields `created_date` and `created_month`.

- created_date: DATETIME  e.g. `2020-12-17 17:23:56`
- created_month: VARCHAR e.g. `17-Aug`

Now the situation- suppose for a record the created_date is `2020-12-17 17:23:56`  and created_month is `17-Aug`.

I am trying to achieve that the created_date should become like this `2020-08-17 17:23:56`. The month from created_month gets updated in created_date. Not very much particular about time or date (17) but year yes.
If I'm doing this
UPDATE my_table SET created_date = STR_TO_DATE(created_month, '%d %b')
It is giving this 0000-08-12 00:00:00 . the year is 0000

Comment: Does `created_month` has `'%d-%b'` format? Does `created_month` is posessed within one year before `created_date` strictly?

Comment: created_date and created_month are same for most records. eg created_date 2020-08-17 17:23:57 , created_month for this record is 17 Aug.  But there are some records for which created_date doesn't match craeted_month. I am trying to put created_month in created_date without altering the year. If I'm doing this UPDATE my_table SET created_date = STR_TO_DATE(created_month, '%d %b') It is giving this 0000-08-12 00:00:00 . the year is 0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> put `created_month` in `created_date` without altering the year

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET created_date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(created_month, 
                                      '-', 
                                      YEAR(created_date), 
                                      ' ', 
                                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(created_date, ' ', -1)), 
                               '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62099852532fa9e5a3ef3b49060159b4)

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me year as 2000. Also there is now a slight change. The created_month is in format DateMonth e.g  7Aug and not 7 Aug. Also some records have 7March and not 7Mar.

Comment: @Abhi Edit fiddle. Add YOUR source structure, data and edited query. Provide new link to the fiddle (into the question text) which shows output incorrectness.

Comment: I will do that, but will it take care of 7March. Few records don't have full month name and not the first three letters.

Comment: I got it .. I am doing it .. please hold on.